# can i resubmit the post to another page after ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that I want to validate on both sides script and php. 
So I thought I can do an ajax request to a page to validate. After that if the validation is successful I want to go to the original page (the action of the form).

Is that possible?

I tried this code but its not working properly. Can someone help please?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkout_form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = "{#$config.base_url_https}/function_ajax.php";

        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize() + "&function_name=validate_checkout",
            success: function (html) {
                if (html == "false") {
                    location.href = "./login.php";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('checkout_form').submit();
                }
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

if its not possible is there any other way to do this?

Comment: save your posted data in some variable and submit it again & again as you want in ajax call

Comment: This is a great idea. How is it not working? Browser error? Does the validation request get received by the server (but with something missing)? Does the actual submit request at the action get received? What's going wrong?

Comment: check your form id is correct or use  $('#checkout_form').submit();

Comment: Can you please provide html code of the form?

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan how ? can you show me what you mean ?

Comment: @arbuthnott document.getElementById('checkout_form').submit(); this line shows error, that its not a function

Comment: @alkoofi why not `$('#checkout_form').submit();` ? You've got jQuery, you might as well use it, rather than mixing the syntaxes for no apparent reason. Shouldn't make any difference, but worth trying, and also for making your code style consistent. But it seems like the logic here is weird - if the validation fails, it will try to submit the form again immediately? How can the user ever correct the problem, if it does that? It will just keep on submitting - and failing - forever, surely?

Comment: @ADyson I did not finish the error handling yet, but apparently you did not get what i want to do here, i want to do validation in ajax after the validation if success i want to go to the action of the form to do the processing of data

Comment: yes but that's not what your code does. Submitting the form using that command will just cause the "submit" Javascript event handler (which you've shown us above) to run again, and again submit the form for validation. You're just repeatedly triggering the exact same process. And according to your code, if `html` equals `"false"`, then it will just redirect to a page called login.php, without submitting any more data.

Comment: @ADyson well this is why I'm asking i need to know what to do instead

Comment: well it's not really clear what you want. You said "i want to go to the action of the form"...but the code above _is_ the action triggered by submitting the form. That's what you've defined should happen when the form is submitted. There is no other process available according to how you have written the code. Please clarify _exactly_ what you want to happen when a) the validation is successful and b) the validation is not successful.

Comment: @ADyson what i mean is `<form action="some_php_to_process.php" method="post">` this is the form action where the data will be processed, but before that i want to go by using ajax to some php that will validate the data for me

Comment: ok but once you defined an ajax submit, that "action" attribute is not used at all. So instead you can just define a second ajax call which goes to that URL instead of the other one, but serialises the same form data. Then you run that ajax call when your validation succeeds. If second call succeeds, then redirect to whatever page you want to go to next. That's one way to do it, anyway.